# Find all the natural numbers $n$ such that $\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}{3}\right\rfloor$ is prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

How many natural numbers $n$ exist for which $\left\lfloor\frac{n^2}{3}\right\rfloor$ is prime?
I thought a lot but I don't  how to calculate the correct part.

Comment: suggest you try the $n$ up to $10$ or so, see which $n$ give primes.

Comment: I try it but I can not prove 3,4 are the only ones

Comment: maybe this identity can be useful $$x\bmod m=x-m\lfloor x/m\rfloor$$

Comment: Look also at Sloane's OEIS: http://oeis.org/A000212

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's pretty clear that $n = 3k$ only works for $k=1$ i.e. $n=3$.

For $n = 3k+1$ we have that $n^2 = 9k^2 + 6k + 1$, so $\lfloor \frac{n^2}{3}\rfloor = 3k^2 + 2k$. If $k$ is even then this number is divisible by $2$. If $k$ is odd, then this number is divisible by $k$, which means that we still have a solution when $k=1$ i.e. $n=4$.

For $n=3k-1$ we can apply a similar technique and get $n^2 = 9k^2 - 6k + 1$ so $\lfloor \frac{n^2}{3}\rfloor = 3k^2 - 2k$. In this case $k=1$ gives us $1$ which is not a prime.

Answer (score 1):

Outline:

You want $3p\leq n^2<3p+3.$

Show that, for $n>3,$ $3p\neq n^2.$

For any $p$, show that $3p+2$ is never a square.

This leaves $3p+1=n^2$, which can be written as $3p=n^2-1.$ Factor the right hand side, and deduce what $n$ can be.